# Parsing POM in Jenkins maven project taking very long time (5-6mins)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm having problem with maven projects that are building on jenkins slave using docker container, it's taking too much time at "Parsing POM" step, about 6mins+. If I build it manually or build it on jenkins master then it take only 30s to finish.
If using freestyle project to build, it take only 3mins to finish but all our devs are using maven project so I need to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks a lot.

Here is the logs, you can see how much time it take for Parsing POM

[image]

Comment: you say "jenkins slave using docker container". is it a new container every time?

Comment: Hi @curious, yes, it's a new container every time, but even with new container, if I build it manually using command mvn clean install, it take only 30s to finish. In jenkins slave it's only very slow at Parsing POM (6mins). Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I guess it's rather the download of the artifact that takes so long. You can see that the next log is "Downloaded artifact", so it has been downloading sth before.

Comment: hi @arifCee do you know what it do in Parsing POM step ? is there any way for me to trace ? thanks. I don't thinks it's network problem as running it manually on container is very fast.

Comment: normally it should take only 1s for parsing pom :(

Comment: Have you configured to use a Maven Job type in Jenkins?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, I used Maven job in Jenkins to build, it took very long time to do Parsing POM (6 mins), if I use ECS as slave then it took only 1s to do Parsing POM :(